Proving that $P[E_1\cap E_2] + P[E_2\cap E_3] + P[E_1\cap E_3] ≥ P[E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3]$
I'm working through an introductory textbook to probability, and I've encountered the following problem:
Prove that $P[E_1\cap E_2] + P[E_2\cap E_3] + P[E_1\cap E_3] ≥ P[E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3]$, where $E_1, E_2, E_3$ are arbitrary events in a probability space $S$. Also, $E_1, E_2, E_3$ are not mutually disjoint.
I would use the monotonicity of probabilities to show that $P[E_1\cap E_2] ≥ P[E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3]$, and since $P[E_2\cap E_3] + P[E_1\cap E_3] ≥ 0$, $P[E_1\cap E_2] + P[E_2\cap E_3] + P[E_1\cap E_3] ≥ P[E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3]$. However, this seems too trivial of a solution to this proof.
I would be very grateful for any feedback.
Thanks,
Eli

Hi, welcome to Math SE. If $XY$ is short for $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $X\land Y$, your method works. If it's short for $X$ or $Y$, i.e. $X\lor Y$, I recommend a Venn diagram.

You're almost there. Monotonicity argument is correct. I would argue further $P(E_i\cap E_j)\geq P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$ for all three cases. Thus the inequality stays when adding all three. You'll get the sum greater equal $3P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$. Skipping the 3 makes it only smaller, so the inequality you want to prove holds.

@PeterStrouvelle No, you are writing unncesasry arguments. What OP has done is complete and completely rigorous.
